# Div's unresponsive to styles when using JavaScript to position elements

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a "grid" using nested for loops. When I inspect the elements in browser they are receiving the styles i'm giving them, yet they aren't actually being positioned. Even when I go in and manually change the css in browser after the JS has loaded they wont change position.

Also, would this be better solved if i used css grid instead?

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
const nodeArray = [].slice.call(nodeList);
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  for (let j = counter; j < (counter + 3); j++){
    nodeArray[j].style.right = leftPos.toString() + "%";
    nodeArray[j].style.top = topPos.toString() + "%";
    nodeArray[j].style.background = 'red';
    nodeArray[j].style.width = '30%';
    nodeArray[j].style.height = '30%';
    leftPos += 33;
  }
  counter += 3;
  leftPos = 0;
  topPos += 33;
 }
}
/*there are 9 div's with class square*/
```

Comment: Are they `position: absolute`?

Comment: I would vote for a css grid approach rather than doing with custom js.

Comment: I would also say use a css grid. Javascript adds it's styles as an inline property. Inline styles always take precedence over other styles. (Other than !important). Or if that's not what you're asking, then make sure the squares have a `position: absolute` and are within a div with a `position:relative` like @BenWest suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forget to set `.square{ position: absolute; }` on the CSS,
With the complete HTML, CSS and JavaScript we can help.

```js
const
nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.square')
let
counter = 0,
leftPos = 0,
topPos = 0

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  nodeList.forEach(e =>{
    e.style.right = `${leftPos}%`
    e.style.top = `${topPos}%`
    e.style.background = 'red'
    e.style.width = '30%'
    e.style.height = '30%'
    leftPos += 33
  })
  counter += 3
  leftPos = 0
  topPos += 33
}
```

```css
 .square{
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="square">Foo</div>
<div class="square">Bar</div>
<div class="square">Foo</div>
<div class="square">Bar</div>
<div class="square">Foo</div>
<div class="square">Bar</div>
<div class="square">Foo</div>
```

You can use forEach instead create another array `const nodeArray = [].slice.call(nodeList);`